# How to grab values from two input boxes in real time with event listener and store in variables in raw JS?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn JS and I am giving myself a small project.

Basically, the project will be a input box that will change the background in real time. It will have two options, single color and gradient.

Single color state will have one input box and a button that switches to gradient mode.

Gradient mode has two input boxes (for the gradient colors).

However, I have a line of code which will run a function every time text is inputted into a input box to add the text added to a variable. The problem is though, since I have to track two input boxes, I can't seem to merge both of the values for Gradient mode since they are in seperate eventListeners.

Does anybody have any idea how I could achieve this?

I need this in RAW JS, no frameworks or JQuery please!

```js
let state = false;

const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
const input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
const switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');
const bodyLoc = document.getElementById('changeColor');

input1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  
})

switcher.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(state)
  if (state == false) {
  state = true;
    checkState();
    bodyLoc.style.backgroundColor = "red"
  }
    else {
      state = false;
      checkState();
      bodyLoc.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
)

checkState = () => {
  if (state == false) {
    input2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    input2.style.display = "block";
  }
}


input1.addEventListener('input',function () {
  input1val = document.getElementById('inputColor1').value;
  console.log(input1val);
})

input2.addEventListener('input',function () {
  input2val = document.getElementById('inputColor2').value;
  console.log(input2val);
})
```

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: "Cabin", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color:#fff;
  transition: 0.4s all ease;
}

.container {
  #inputBox {
    display:flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    #input1,#input2 {
      input {
        height:20px;
        border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
        border:1px solid #D8D8D8;
        padding:10px;
      }
    }
    
    #input2 {
      display:none;
    }
    .inputSubmit {
      #changeType {
        height:42px;
        background-color:#fff;
        border:1px solid #F5F5F5;
        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
        width:80px;
        transition: 0.2s all ease;
        &:hover {
          cursor:pointer;
          background:#4A00E0;
          color:white;
          transition: 0.2s all ease;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:wght@400;600&display=swap');
</style>

<body id="changeColor">
<div class="container">
  <div id="inputBox">
    <div id="input1">
      <input type="text" id="inputColor1">
    </div>
    <div id="input2">
      <input type="text" id="inputColor2">
    </div>
    <div class="inputSubmit">
      <input type="submit" id="switcher" value="Gradient">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
```

JS

```
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
const input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
const switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');
const bodyLoc = document.getElementById('changeColor');

input1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  
})

switcher.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(state)
  if (state == false) {
  state = true;
    checkState();
  }
    else {
      state = false;
      checkState();
  }
}
)

checkState = () => {
  if (state == false) {
    input2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    input2.style.display = "block";
  }
}


input1.addEventListener('input',function () {
  input1val = document.getElementById('inputColor1').value;
  console.log(input1val);
})

input2.addEventListener('input',function () {
  input2val = document.getElementById('inputColor2').value;
  console.log(input2val);
})
```

HTML

````
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:wght@400;600&display=swap');
</style>

<body id="changeColor">
<div class="container">
  <div id="inputBox">
    <div id="input1">
      <input type="text" id="inputColor">
    </div>
    <div id="input2">
      <input type="text" id="inputColor">
    </div>
    <div class="inputSubmit">
      <input type="submit" id="changeType" value="Gradient">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>```
````

Comment: Since I can't edit your post could you consider using a code snippet so that I can run your code right here? Thanks!

Comment: Hi!

You could use my codepen code if you like?

https://codepen.io/DonnieBerryDev/pen/oNzZzrY

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack Overflow kinda! Added the snippet!

Comment: Thanks! Have you tried adding the input into a global variable?

Comment: (Sorry, new to JS!)

I've tried adding the event listener outside of any function but because the var is INSIDE the listener, I can't seem to bring it out due to scope?

I need the listener because I need updates in real time, as data is entered

Comment: Yeah, you can just set the variable to nothing OUTSIDE of the function: `var gradientInput;`. INSIDE of the function just use `gradientInput = input.value`. [Seen here](https://codepen.io/Rohittt/pen/BaLWQLO?editors=1111)

Comment: Oh I am being silly, thanks for that! completely forgot I can do that!

Comment: Id must be unique, you have 2 id="inputColor"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your aim with this but by simply adding:

```
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs[0].addEventListener('keyDown', ()=>{
console.log(inputs[0].value)
})

inputs[1].addEventListener('keyDown', ()=>{
console.log(inputs[1].value)
})
```

Gives back the value instantly as you write just store them in a let or var variable on global scope like this:

```
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let input1 = "";
let input2 = "";
inputs[0].addEventListener('keyDown', ()=>{
input1 = inputs[0].value;
})

inputs[1].addEventListener('keyDown', ()=>{
input2 = inputs[1].value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that hook events:`cut/paste` and `propertychange` (for IE) also important

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const output = document.querySelector("#output");

const showText = () => {
  output.textContent = input.value;
};

input.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  showText();
});

input.addEventListener("cut", () => {
  setTimeout(() => showText(), 0);
});

input.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => showText(), 0);
});

input.addEventListener("propertychange", (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => showText(), 0);
});
```

```html
<h1>Hook input in vanilla js!</h1>
<input type="text">
<p id="output"></p>`;
```

Comment: Why the `setTimeOut`s?

Comment: Because we need time when value changes after paste or cut and It's best way - use event loop queue (we'll get value must fast as possible)

Comment: Or you could use the `input` event that handles this without modification : https://javascript.info/events-change-input

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a button for this and maintain the state manually, use elements that do this for you, like radio buttons. Could also adapt this for a checkbox.

```js
function applyBackground() {
  //Get Start Color
  var start = document.getElementById("startColor").value;
  //Get end color
  var end = document.getElementById("endColor").value;
  //Get Mode
  var mode = document.querySelector("#switcher [type=radio]:checked").value;
  //Add your logic for updating body style
  console.log(`start: ${start}, end: ${end}, mode: ${mode}`);    
}

//event Handlers for radio buttons
document.querySelectorAll("#switcher input[type=radio]").forEach((rdo) => {
  rdo.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var isGradient = this.value === "gradient";
    //Show/Hide end color
    document.getElementById("endContainer").classList.toggle("hidden", !isGradient);
    //Change text of start color
    document.querySelector("[for=startColor]").innerText = isGradient ? "Start Color" : "Color";
    //Apply on swap
    applyBackground();
  });
});

//event handler for text box
document.querySelectorAll("#colors input[type=text]").forEach((rdo) => {
  rdo.addEventListener("input", applyBackground);
});
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: "Cabin", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color:#fff;
  transition: 0.4s all ease;
}

.container {
  #inputBox {
    display:flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    #input1,#input2 {
      input {
        height:20px;
        border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
        border:1px solid #D8D8D8;
        padding:10px;
      }
    }
    
    #input2 {
      display:none;
    }
    .inputSubmit {
      #changeType {
        height:42px;
        background-color:#fff;
        border:1px solid #F5F5F5;
        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
        width:80px;
        transition: 0.2s all ease;
        &:hover {
          cursor:pointer;
          background:#4A00E0;
          color:white;
          transition: 0.2s all ease;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:wght@400;600&display=swap');
</style>

<body id="changeColor">
<div class="container">
  <fieldset id="switcher">
    <legend>Mode</legend>
    <label>Single color <input type="radio" name="rdoMode" value="single" checked></label>
    <label>Gradient <input type="radio" name="rdoMode" value="gradient"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <div>
    <div id="colors">
    <div>
      <label for="startColor">Color</label>
      <input type="text" id="startColor">
    </div>
    <div id="endContainer" class="hidden">
      <label for="endColor">End Color</label>
      <input type="text" id="endColor">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
```